# Convergence of quotients and substractions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How would you prove the following:

Assume that $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with $b_n\not = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1\Leftrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0$

Comment: The last part is the sum of the difference series$=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false. Take $b_n=n^2+1$ and $a_n = n^2$. Then $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$ and $\lim (a_n - b_n) = -1$.

Comment: You could have taken in both cases $\;n\;$ , as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

For $a \in \mathbb R$ let $a_n=n+a$ and $b_n=n$. Then $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$, but $\lim (a_n - b_n) = a$.